# How to calculate bitcoins in fees spent dailly? (Avg)

Tags: bitcoin-core

From https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/ I can see a list of bitcoin satoshi fees/byte

From https://thenextweb.com/hardfork/2018/07/12/bitcoin-block-size/ I can see that we can have block sizes of up to 2mb with segwit.

If I assume that segwit adoption increases in the next year, then I will base all calculations on the block size being ~2mb.

How do I back-of-envelope calculate total fees in bitcoin spent daily?

Assuming 6 blocks / hour, & with 24 hours in a day, is it:

~satoshiFee * 2m * 6 * 24

Which, assuming an average satoshi fee of 10 (using https://bitcoinfees.info/)

Gives:

10 * 2m * 6 * 24

And in BTC that's divided by 10^8, so we'd get:

20m * 144 / 10^8 = 28.8

Is that correct?

Comment: If you head to a place like this:
https://www.blockchain.com/explorer and click on one of the blocks you'll see a summary screen.

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000012ca146d2d1dc07d3157094b019ee59513e7a4caafc34e

Block reward is at the end of the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that look correct.

From https://bitcoinfees.info/, the current average fee rate listed at the bottom of the chart is 24 satoshis/byte. To calculate the total fees in a day you want `fee rate` * `total bytes` = `total satoshis`.

Assuming 2MB block size,

`fee rate` = `24 satoshis/byte`
`total bytes` = `2MB * 6 * 24` = `288MB`

`total btc` = `total satoshis / 1e8`
`total btc` = `(24 * 288M) / 1e8` = `69.12 BTC`